# Is it possible to use nested folders in gridsome when using the source-filesystem plugin?

Tags: gridsome, gridsome-plugin, gridsome-source-filesystem

My desired content folder structure is as follows:

```
- content (directory)
-- home.md

-- trip_A (directory)
--- intro.md
--- day_1.md
--- day_2.md

-- trip_B (directory)
--- intro.md
--- day_1.md
```

I would ideally like to define this as a single "source" for the `@gridsome/source-filesystem` plugin so that the addition of future sub-folders are automatically populated in the source.

However, it appears that I may have to manually specify a separate `@gridsome/source-filesystem` source for each of the sub-folders? Is this correct, or is there a workaround of sorts?

For example:

- How do I create a generic source for all trip posts (regardless of trip A, B, C or, in future, trip D) that uses a `typeName` (i.e. template page) of type `Trip` but hosts each of these pages at their respective parent directories, e.g. `/tripA/day_1.html`, `/tripB/day_1.html` etc? The config seems to take a single `pathPrefix` unless there is a way to use a dynamic wild card route?
- How do I use different types? Here it seems to make sense to create a separate `source-filesystem` entry with a different `typeName`, unless there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the simplest solution to this problem is to manually assign the path in the Templates part of the gridsome config [using a function](https://gridsome.org/docs/templates/#setup-templates)

IE, for this plugin setup...

```
var plugins = [
 {
    use: '@gridsome/source-filesystem',
    options: {
      path: '**/*.md',
      baseDir: 'temp/docs',
      typeName: 'Doc'
    }
  }
];
```

and this function to generate the path...

```
function slugify(node) {
  var text = node.title;
  console.log(node);  
  var text = text.toString().toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
    .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
    .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
    return  node.fileInfo.directory + '/' + text;
}
```

and this Gridsome config that references the function in the templates object...

```
var gridsomeConfig = {
  siteName: siteName,
  icon: {
    favicon: favicon,
    touchicon: favicon
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  templates: {
    Doc:
      (node) => {
        return `/docs/${slugify(node)}/`
      }    
  }
}
```

and given some markdown files in various subdirectories, i.e. /api and /ui...

You will get content of type Doc at /docs/ui, /docs/api, etc. With the need for only one template (GraphQL type -- meaning same query for all docs).

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried in your Gridsome config? Something like the following should collect all the files in the `content` directory and any of its subfolders:

```js
{
   use: '@gridsome/source-filesystem',
   options: {
      path: './content/**/*.md',
      typeName: 'Post',  
   }
}
```

If you add a `trip_C` in future it will be included in the collection automatically.

Alternatively, you can use a single asterisk in the glob pattern (`path: 'content/*/*.md'`) if you don't want to scan subfolders recursively.

This works because you've nested everything in `content`. It's also possible to specify a list of patterns in the `path` field which might work if you want to combine files from multiple top-level directories together in a single collection.

Does that help?

Comment: I haven't yet tried this, though I wonder if I'll run into issues where if everything is bundled into a single source then is there a way to conveniently filter the request by sub-folder?

Comment: A point of confusion for me is: how do you tell `source-filesystem` to host trip pages at different parent directories, hence the question of whether it was necessary to create a distinct collection for each trip. I've embellished the original question to add this more explicitly.